# Can't ignore target folder by Tortoise SVN client

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I want to ignore target folder each time I commit code change using Tortoise SVN client on Window 7. So I right click on target folder and select **TortoiseSVN -> Unversion and add to ignored list**. However, next time I commit from the parent folder of target, I still see it on the list to be committed. Am I missed something to get it done?

Comment: What exactly you see when you are trying to commit the "delete and ignore"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [TortoiseSVN Manual](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-ignore.html), especially this part: ["Ignore files which are already versioned"](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-howto-unversion.html).

When you run "Unversion and add to ignore list" command it will schedule the file or a folder to be removed on next commit and will add it to ignore list. You need to commit this change to repository.

> If the files are already in the repository, they have to be deleted
>   from the repository and added to the ignore list. Fortunately
>   TortoiseSVN has a convenient shortcut for doing this. **TortoiseSVN →
>   Unversion and add to ignore list will first mark the file/folder for
>   deletion from the repository, keeping the local copy. It also adds
>   this item to the ignore list so that it will not be added back into
>   Subversion again by mistake. Once this is done you just need to commit
>   the parent folder.**

Comment: Thanks. You're right. I just recognize that target folder is already in SVN server. I delete it from server and now target is not now on commit list any more. Thank you again.